# trying to adding legend to a plot with different data frame in the same graphic

Tags: r

I'm trying to add legend to the plot in the same graphic with three differents data frame, for examlpe I would like that in my graphic appear three legend with the three different data values that I'm using. 
I have dataframe = df, fil_PP_LP, fil_PP_LLP

`ggplot()+ geom_line(data=df,aes(x=fecha,y=result_NS))+
  geom_point(aes(x = fecha, y = result_PP), data = fil_PP_LP, colour ="red")+
  geom_point(aes(x = fecha, y = result_NS), data = fil_PP_LLP, colour = "blue")+ ylab("Nivel de Stock")`

Comment: There are N solutions to this problem. You can make each chart separate and then merge them with `cowplot::plot_grid()`, or any similar function, or you can simply join your database and use `facet_wrap()` or `facet_grid()` from `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding `scale_colour_identity()` might be the answer you're looking for. This would add a legend for the blue and red points that you specified. It would help if we could see the code you used to create your data and a picture of your desired output. You can see the `reprex` and `datapasta` to give us a useable dataset.

https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/datapasta-reprex.html